# Search query builder

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, query

I want to search pages, the user who made the page sets a publish begindate (Time/date column)
Now I want to know how to select a Column with a filter (KQL).
For example `write>2016-1-01` this works. 
How do I change write with the column name?

Columnname: BegindatumOWSDATE
This doesnt work: `BegindatumOWSDATE >2016-03-27`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BegindatumOWSDATE` is text type managed property. You can't compare date with text type.

You need to map that crawled property to managed property with DATE type.
Only **RefinableDate** is date type (RefinableDate00 - RefinableDate19).

Choose one RefinableDate in managed properties (YOURSITE/_layouts/15/listmanagedproperties.aspx?level=sitecol) for ex. RefinableDate00.

Edit that RefinableDate00 managed property and map your crawled property `ows_q_DATE_Begindatum`.

Then you can compare RefinableDate00<2016-03-27 ; RefinableDate00>2016-03-27 ...

:)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will give it a try tonight :)